# How to bind events inside a element in a directive in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, event-handling

I have a directive like this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Employee Name" ng-keyup="checkVal(this)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Designation" ng-keyup="checkVal(this)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" ng-keyup="checkVal(this)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Address" ng-keyup="checkVal(this)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" ng-keyup="checkVal(this)" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-remove" ng-click="addEmployee()"></button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

now, what **i want to do bind a keyup event inside the input element and get the value entered inside the input**, how can id do that? My directive code is this

```
app.directive('addEmployee', function () {
                return {
                    restrict: 'A',
                    templateUrl: '/Template/AddEmployee.html',
                    link: function (scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
                        scope.checkVal = function (element) {
                            debugger;
                        };
                    }
                };
            });
```

Comment: instead of `this` pass `$event.target` like `ng-keyup="checkVal($event.traget)"`, but why you need element there? You could think of using `ng-model`

Comment: all i want is to get the value of the input which triggered the keyup event, thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: Better use, `ng-model` over each input.. likewise I suggested in my last comment..

Comment: it is not working with ng-model

Comment: You better define a controller for your directive and handle the event inside the controller.